# Javascript window.location.href onClick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a basic html page and basic Javascript in the head. I'm trying to redirect using Javascript once the function is activated through onClick but window.location.href wont work. window.alert works and everything else.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Testing Aff Links</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc(){

    window.location.href="http://youtube.com";
}
</script>
</head>



<body>

Link <a href="http://google.com" class="link" onClick="myfunc()">Link #1</a>

  </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me...

Comment: It worked for me in the beginning as well and all of a sudden stopped working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return false` from the `onclick` attribute to prevent the default action:

```
Link <a href="http://google.com" class="link" onClick="myfunc(); return false;">Link #1</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are redirecting twice. Change it to:

```
Link <a href="javascript:;" class="link" onClick="myfunc()">Link #1</a>
```